# Why do these output differ while I try to execute the isKindOfClass in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In these both cases the NSString has not been NIL. In first case it has been failure.Can you anyone please explain me about these?

```
NSString *str1 = @"str";
if (![str1 isKindOfClass:Nil]) {
    NSLog(@"true");
}
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str"];
if (![str2 isKindOfClass:Nil]) {
     NSLog(@"true");
}
```

Comment: r u trying to check a nil string ?

Comment: In both cases it is returning true while I am running code

Comment: No way. Are you sure?

Comment: 1) What version of iOS and what device are you testing this with? 2) What's the point of this code? You would never use such code for real. It's pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy ios 9. any difference between  __NSCFConstantString and  __NSCFString. i think both are sub classes of nsstring

Comment: Those are all part of the "NSString" class cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do these output differ?

`Nil` is not a class object that you can use with `isKindOfClass:`. As the documentation does not say anything about passing `Nil` it's just undefined. In my experiments I always get `YES` but the result might be just random.

If you want to check if a variable is nil just use plain old C equality:

```
NSString *str1 = @"str";
if (str1 != nil) {           // explicit
    NSLog(@"true");
}
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str"];
if (str2) {                  // or just like this
    NSLog(@"true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**isKindOfClass**

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from
>   that class.

If you want to check whether string is nil or not, you can simply do this:

```
if(str1){
        NSLog(@"string is not nil");
    }
```

Comment: ok. But in case str2 it got an log. I got that str1 is not a nil. But how it fails

Comment: i checked your code. Both the conditions executed. None of them failed